# sort list of dicts by different keys in python

Tags: python

here is the list of dict I have:

```
[{'title': 'C'}, {'contentTitle':'B'}, {'title': 'A'}]
```

In python, is it possible to write a comparator to sort the list, which would first look value under `title` and if there is no `title`, use the value under `contentTitle`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to look up a key without raising an exception:

```
>>> lst = [{'title': 'C'}, {'contentTitle':'B'}, {'title': 'A'}]
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x.get("title") or x.get("contentTitle"))
[{'title': 'A'}, {'contentTitle': 'B'}, {'title': 'C'}]
```

Comment: For the sake of code golf, that can be shortened somewhat `sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x.get("title", x.get("contentTitle")))`